# delete a property or set it to null?

Tags: javascript

Maybe this is a naive question, but I have to ask for expert opinions...

I often use temporary properties in objects that indicate the object's state. One of the states is when the property evaluates to `false`. For example:

```
// inside some method:
this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('hello world');
}, 1000);

...

// inside another method:
if (this.timer) {
  clearTimeout(this.timer);
  this.timer = null;
}
```

When I clear my timer, I can either assign `null` to it as I do above, or I can delete it from the object:

```
delete this.timer;
```

I am not sure which way is preferred. What are disadvantages of deleting the property rather than setting it to `null`?

EDIT:

I of course realize that when I delete a property, the property goes away and when I set it to either `null` or `undefined` it is still there. The question is is it an accepted practice  to delete a property in circumstances as above. I suppose not because it is slower...

Comment: from the performance point of view. deleting could be a overkill. null could be the better option, since you might be reusing the property again.you dont have to recreate the property everytime.

Comment: That depends on, if you're going to use  `timer` property later. If not, you can delete it as well. If you're going to assign a new timer, or you need to check if `timer` exists, then it's better to set it to `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the property removes the property whereas setting it to null makes it… `null`. Both are conceptually different:

- With deleting the property, you're inferring that the timer **no longer exists**.
- Setting it to `null` would infer that the timer **no longer has a value**, but still exists.

Comment: `delete this.timer` is not the same as `this.timer = undefined` nor `this.timer = null`. `undefined` is also a value, like `null`. But a type of a value can be undefined: `typeof(this.timer) == "undefined"`

Answer (score 0):

With `delete this.timer`, you remove the `timer` key of your current `this` object → the key doesn't exist anymore.

With `this.timer = null`, you assign the `null` value to the `timer` key → the key still exists.

If you transform your `this` object to JSON, the `timer` can be here or not, same for the `for (key in this) {…}`

Answer (score 0):

`delete` will really remove the property from its owner, in your code is `this` object.
But set property to `null` or `undefined` won't do that.

You can check it using this:

```
for(var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        console.log(i, '' + obj[i]);
    }
}
```